# How to create Dataframes on partitioned files

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 1000+ parquet files in a folder, which is a partitioned folder.
Now we got a requirement to use those files to perform some transformations on it.
i need to create data frame using those parquet file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
DF = sqlContext.read.parquet(r"<folderpath>/*")
```

`*` indicates all files present under the specified folder.

`DF` will be a dataframe that will contain the data from all the parquet files inside the `<folderpath>`. Then you can perform your transformation on `DF`.